# Regex search & replace inline CSS style

Tags: html, css, regex, sublimetext2

I need to search & replace inside HTML tags, CSS that was inlined, in order to avoid using the `style=""` attribute inline.

I.e. replace something that looks like this:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"  style="font-family: Helvetica;line-height: 100%;margin-top: 20px; text-align: left;vertical-align: bottom;color: #202020">
```

into something like that:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" font-family="Helvetica" line-height="100%" margin-top="20px" text-align="left" vertical-align="bottom" color="#202020">
```

Does someone know the regex for search & replace I would have to write in order to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do that in a single pass. I'd do this with `preg_replace_callback` in PHP. Start with `style="(.+?)"`. Also no way to know if attributes are valid going this route..

Comment: What are you trying to do? A `font-family` attribute on a `table` tag won't do anything at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this regex replacement:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|\bstyle=")([^:]*):\s*([^;]*)[;"](?=[^>]*>)
```

Replace with (mind the space at the end):

```
$1="$2"
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bV8vQ7/1)

**EXPLANATION**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|\bstyle=")` - A boundary where we'll start our matching. The boundary is the end of the previous match (`\G(?!^)`) or `style="` (due to `\bstyle="`).
- `([^:]*)` - The 1st capturing group that holds a sequence of 0 or more characters other than `:`
- `:` - a literal `:`
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace
- `([^;]*)` - The 2nd capturing group that holds a sequence of 0 or more characters other than `;`
- `[;"]` - Either a `;` or `"`
- `(?=[^>]*>)` - We check the ending boundary to make sure we are inside a closing tag.

Comment: I added explanations.

Comment: thanks but your regex fails when there 2 `style="some css style"` in the same string

Comment: @eric: Please provide some sample input string (better as a regex101.com link). Just guessing: maybe `(?:\G(?!^)|\bstyle=")([^:>]*):\s*([^;>]*)[;"](?=[^>]*>)` will work for you.

Comment: for example: `
<div><span style="line-height: 1.42857;">GDP Growth</span><br></div><div>&nbsp; in 2014</div><div>&nbsp; &nbsp; 2.9%</div>
<div><span style="line-height: 1.42857;">GDP in 2014</span><br></div><div>&nbsp;S$390.0 Bil</div>
how to raise funding for a bussiness`

Answer (score 5):

You could do it like this:

1. Match `style="(.*?)"` and save the captured group to a variable.
2. On that variable, match `([a-zA-Z-]+):\s*(.*?)\s*;` and replace it with `{1}="{2}"`.
3. Replace `style=".*?"` with the result of number 2.

Comment: `style="(.*?)"` was great, and in my case I used the same matching for replacing all these absolute height definitions with `height='auto'`. Very helpful!

Comment: Thank you so much, you've just saved me like 2 hours of work!